# Policies Laravel not sending variable to controller

Tags: laravel

I'm new at Laravel, and I'm trying to make Policies that will prevent user that doesn't have id_level 1 which is admin to access InventarisController, but the InventarisPolicy doesn't send variable to InventarisController.

it's my Inventaris Policies

> InventarisPolicy.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\{User, Level};
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class InventarisPolicy

{
use HandlesAuthorization;

/**
 * Create a new policy instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

public function inventaris_add(User $user)
{
    $user->id_level == 1;
    // dd($user);
    // $user->id_level == 2;
}
}
```

it's my Inventaris Controller

> InventarisController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\{Inventaris, DetailPinjamanView};
// use Illuminate\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
// use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class InventarisController extends Controller
{
    /**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    // $viewpinjaman = DetailPinjamanView::all();
    $this->authorize('inventaris_add', $user);

    $inventaris = Inventaris::all();
    return view('index', compact('inventaris'));
}
```

Comment: When you’re new to a framework, it’s usually a good idea to stick to its conventions. Your policy method should be called “create”, not “inventaris_add”. Also check you’ve associated the policy with your `Inventaris` model in your `AuthServiceProvider` class.

Comment: Also, your `index` method should probably just be checking if a user can view any inventory, not if they can _create_ inventory. If you’re using a resource controller then you can automatically generate a policy with all your methods via `php artisan make:policy InventarisPolicy --model=Inventaris`.

Comment: im following someone youtube videos, but it's not turn out the same

Comment: yes, that was the purpose to just view/not the inventaris, the name is wrong because it was for another feature actually but im testing it for authorize user